# Obtain Distinct top 1 columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, distinct

I am writing a stored procedure for a project in SQL Server 2014 and I have this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE FOF_MejorVendedor
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 
        F.Nombre, Em.Nombre, (P.Precio * CA.Cantidad)  as 'Ganancia' 
    FROM
        dbo.FO_Carrito CA
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Solicitud S on S.ID = CA.FK_SolicitudC
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Recibo R ON R.FK_Solicitud = S.ID
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Productos P ON P.ID = CA.FK_ProductosC 
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Cliente C ON C.ID = S.FK_Cliente
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Estante E ON E.FK_Producto = P.ID
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_PasilloXDepartamento PD ON PD.FK_Estante = E.NumeroEstante
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Encargado En ON En.ID = PD.FK_Encargado
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Empleado Em ON Em.ID = En.FK_EmpleadoE 
    JOIN
        dbo.FO_Departamento D ON D.ID = PD.FK_Departamento
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_Ferreteria F ON D.FK_Ferreteria = F.ID
    JOIN 
        dbo.FO_EmpleadosXFerreteria EF ON EF.FK_Ferreterias = F.ID 
    GROUP BY
        F.Nombre, Em.Nombre, (P.Precio * CA.Cantidad)
    ORDER BY 
        Ganancia DESC
END
```

But I am only getting the Top 1 of 'Ganancia' but I want to get it for each distinct value in the column "F.Nombre". How can I modify the query?

Comment: Remove the top 1. You do realize that top 1 returns only 1 row right? Your group by will be grouping the rows into sets. Removing the top 1 will return distinct rows for F.Nombre and Em.Nombre

Comment: I would also suggest that you stop using a column named ID in every table. That is a design pattern that is painful to work with. The column name should stay the same in every table. ProductID should remain unchanged. And naming your columns as FK_ is a bad idea. What happens if that is no longer a foreign key? You either have to update all of your code or live with a column that is named misleading. Embedding usage into the name is not a good approach to database design.

Comment: Yes I know, but if i delete the TOP 1, it doesn't  group me by distinct instances of "F.Nombre"

Comment: You aren't getting distinct values of F.Nombre anyway. You are only getting 1. Take Em.Nombre out of the query and the group by, use MAX(Em.Nombre) or maybe something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retrieving the top record because you using `Top 1` clause, did u believe !

so remove it and the

```
 Group by
```

will show the result as distinct.